# Crystal Report 13 Suppressing section conditionally or programmatically

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, crystal-reports

I am using crystal report 13 with visual studio 2010. Earlier I had worked with crystal report XI. in crystal report XI if I need to suppress any section I just double click on the section to open the code window and write conditions for suppressing the section. But How can I achieve the same in crystal report 13. I searched and found that I will have to write condition in formula. but I have to execute a query and based on that result i have to suppress the section.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to Suppress any sections in c# you can do that like this:

```
CRAXDRT.Report report1 = new CRAXDRT.Report();
CRAXDRT.Application app1 = new CRAXDRT.Application();

report1 = app1.OpenReport("Test.rpt", OpenReportMethod.OpenReportByDefault);
report1.Sections[x].Suppress = true;
```